# How to use the Mac book pro's iSight camera in ROS for the webcam?

Tags: ros, mac, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a ROS newbie and would like to use the internal camera called I believe iSight on my Mac Book Pro laptop to do some image processing development. I would like to know if anyone else has gone down this path and learn from their experinces. I'm running Parallels with Ubuntu 14.04 on my Mac. Thanks for any help, Phil.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234745/how-to-use-the-mac-book-pro%27s-isight-camera-in-ros-for-the-webcam?/) by [pbarile](https://answers.ros.org/users/26390/pbarile/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The iSight camera is a regular USB UVC webcam. You can tell Parallels to pass the camera through to the VM, and then use [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) to publish images from it in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbarile](https://answers.ros.org/users/26390/pbarile/) on 2016-05-21**:
Dan, thanks for the help!  I got further by installing the usb_cam package and then executing it.  I'm getting the same 'CalibrationFile is missing'  error that is described at the very bottom of this link: http://laukh.com/ros/usb_cam/. Can you tell me how/if I need to calibrate? I'm very confused.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2016-05-22**:
If you want to calibrate your camera, you can use [camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration). Whether or not you need to do that depends entirely on your application. If you don't want to calibrate, you can ignore those messages.